# 3D web app for MAC and Windows

Tags: windows, macos, web, 3d

I need to develop a web based browser application that will use the 3d accelleration graphic card of the client.
This app need to work on MAC and Windows system client, Safari, Firefox, IE...
I'm started it with ASP.NET and Silverlight 5, but i've discovered that 3D features on MAC client not work (http://michaelcrump.net/silverlight-5-has-been-released-plus-other-info)...

There is any solution to develop an application, web based server side, that will run in Mac and Windows browser, with 3D technology and cross-platform?

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is cross-platform and can do 3D.  For example, http://threejs.org/.

Java applets are cross-platform and can do 3D.  For example, http://jogamp.org/jogl/www/.